# How can I develop locally when using Iguazio platform?

Tags: python, mlops, nuclio, mlrun

I want to be able to test my jobs and code on my local machine before executing on a remote cluster. Ideally this will not require a lot of setup on my end. Is this possible?

Comment: yes,  this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. A common development pattern with the Iguazio platform is to utilize a local version of MLRun and Nuclio on a laptop/workstation and move/execute jobs on the cluster at a later point.

There are two main options for installing MLRun and Nuclio on a local environment:

- `docker-compose` - Simpler and easier to get up and running, however restricted to running jobs within the environment it was executed in (i.e. Jupyter or IDE). This means you cannot specify resources like CPU/MEM/GPU to run a particular job. This approach is great for quickly getting up and running. Instructions can be found [here](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/install/local-docker.html).
- `Kubernetes` - More complex to get up and running, but allows for running jobs in their own containers with specified CPU/MEM/GPU resources. This approach is a better for better emulating capabilities of the Iguazio platform in a local environment. Instructions can be found [here](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/install/kubernetes.html).

Once you have installed MLRun and Nuclio using one of the above options and have created a job/function you can test it locally as well as deploy to the Iguazio cluster directly from your local development environment:

- To run your job locally, utilize the `local=True` flag when specifying your MLRun function like in the [Quick-Start guide](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/tutorial/01-mlrun-basics.html#running-the-mlrun-function-locally).
- To run your job remotely, specify the required environment files to allow connectivity to the Iguazio cluster as specified in this [guide](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/install/remote.html#load-the-configuration-and-credential-environmental-variables-from-file), and run your job with `local=False`